# markerClusterer: Update cluster icon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

I'm using markerClusterer: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html

and my problem is this:

The user, on the map can edit the icon of the markers.

So, I want that one marker's icon is changed, the cluster parent must recalculate the cluster icon.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

The .CALCULATOR() function is recalled every time you zoom in and zoom out the map, so is automagically resolved.